# Remove the elements and contents before an element

Tags: jquery, forms

I am trying to remove the elements and contents 
before a  link inside a div when a user clicks a button. 
What is the best way to do it??

```
<div id="dialog" class="window">  

         //will be inserted a <select> element and few text here 
         //but I want to clear them after the user click a button

    <a href="#" class="close">Close it</a>  // I want to keep this <a> link.    

    </div>
```

My Jquery

```
$('.model').click(function(e) {  

   $("#dialog").empty();  //I can't use this because <a> will be deleted. Any better ideas?         

});
```

Thanks for the reply...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just wrap all those elements in a div and remove them

```
$('#select-wrapper').remove();
```

or do it  a little more friendlier

```
$('#select-wrapper').fadeOut(500, function() { $(this).remove(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

try putting the content you want removed in its own div. Then it will be simple jquery to hide/remove the div on the click event.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
$('.model').click(function(e) {  
  $("#dialog").children(":not(.close)").remove();
});
```

This just removes all children using [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) without the `close` class on them.  Or just clone and re-add the link using [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/), like this:

```
$('.model').click(function(e) {  
  $("#dialog a.close").clone(true).appendTo($("#dialog").empty());
});
```

Comment: True, but that won't remove text nodes (nodeType == 3's). I think the way to go here would be to incorporate a wrapper as per @alex's suggestion.

Comment: @karim - I'd actually clone the `<a>`, re-add it, but I'm not sure of his exact markup...hard to tell what's nested from the question

Comment: Thanks. I love your solution...:D +1.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to keep that `a` link, or do you just want that div to contain a link that looks just like it afterwards?

Why not just overwrite innerHTML with `<a href="#" class="close">Close it</a>`?

I understand that if that link has changed in some way beyond your knowledge or control, then you'd have to keep it, but unless that is the case, a lookalike will do the trick.

Comment: I need to keep that link to make my jquery works. Thanks for the tip though. +1